# Ubuntu Touchpad and rightarrow not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, dell-vostro

I have 2 issues with my Dell Vostro Laptop.
    1: Touch pad doesn't work and
    2: The right arrow doesn't work

I have ubuntu 16.04.

Recently with no updates, and no specific installations the touchpad and the 2 accompanying buttons in my laptop has stopped working.

I tried the below steps and now, the touchpad works for :
1: while entering the prompt [GUI login credentials]
2: It works perfectly fine for another user

I tried as below :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

replace,

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"

sudo update-grub
```

command. and then restart OS,

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Please let me know did I miss anything ?

Regards,

Comment: Does the right arrow key work for the other user?

Comment: No. The right arrow key doesn't work for both the users.

Comment: Is "disable touchpad while typing" enabled for any of the users? Btw you tagged your question with 14.04.